# Fit image inside as background button when button is clicked

Tags: html, css, angular, button

When input type file is clicked, I want to show the selected image as background of the button.

But the following code doesn't fit(cover) the image inside the button after the image is selected.

**Html**

```css
input#file {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 400px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='file' id="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" class="form-control btn btn-primary" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + imageURL + ') center center no-repeat #e4e4e4'}">
```

**Component**

```
onSelectFile(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.imageURL = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background` style you used in `input` overwrote the `background-size` as `center center`.
You should use the following code to set the `background-size: cover`.

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + imageURL + ') center center / cover no-repeat #e4e4e4'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `background-size` to the style of the button in question. It defaults to `auto` which shows actual size, not fit to container.

Add either `background-size: cover` (the image will fill the button but maybe not show the whole image. Or `background-size: contain` (the whole image will be forced to fit in the button, even if it looks squashed).